# MVC Role Authorization via OpenId from IdentityServer 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm in the process of trying to learn identity server 4 and I have everything working apart from Role authorization in my MVC client (it works fine in my Web API via JWT Bearer which is called from my MVC client).

I've been searching and trying to implement potential fixes for hours, but I don't seem to be getting any further, so I assume I am missing a small, but crucial, part of the puzzle.

#### This is (part) of my MVC client StartUp:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = appSettings.IdentityUrl;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Scope.Add("web_api");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

    // I was under the impression that was the 'magic' part which mapped claims to roles for use with the Authorize() attribute
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
}
```

#### This is the payload of the access_token I get once I log in, as you can see, the Roles are there:

```
{
    "nbf": 1592473463,
    "exp": 1592477063,
    "iss": "https://localhost:5000",
    "aud": "web_api",
    "client_id": "mvc",
    "sub": "b2657e83-4256-4fe2-86e9-3bfa53d462e2",
    "auth_time": 1592473458,
    "idp": "local",
    "is_enabled": "True",
    "role": [
        "Player",
        "Admin"
    ],
    "scope": [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "web_api",
        "offline_access"
    ],
    "amr": [
    "pwd"
    ]
}
```

#### Example MVC controller endpoint which returns access denied:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthorisedOnly()
{
    ...SNIP...

    return View("Access", vm);
}
```

I'm assuming, possibly incorrectly, that if my access_token has the Roles in it, then my Identity database and `ProfileService` is set up correctly. (I add the roles in the `GetProfileDataAsync` of the `ProfileService`).

Any suggestions would be welcome, and if you need any more information about my setup, then please let me know. I didn't want to bloat the question with loads of irrelevant config data.

Comment: The problem seems to be the mapping, please read [this article](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [article](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/) @RuardvanElburg mentioned in his comment I have found the answer. Not so much the article itself, but a snippet of code dealing with `TokenValidationParamters` which mentioned 'role' that I saw and thought might do the trick. The comments in the article also helped me, much more than the main article, but that's par for the course with official Identity Server articles/documentation!

```
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = "name",
    RoleClaimType = "role"
};

//options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
```